# Is it possible to set a button width to match parent in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Im working with a button in kotlin, for example i have this code:

```
val listHorizontal =  LinearLayout(this);
listHorizontal.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL)
val button1 = Button(this)
button1.text= "horario"
val button2 = Button (this)
button2.width = 100
listHorizontal.addView(boton1)
listHorizontal.addView(boton2)
```

So i want to set button2 to its width at Match_Parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example if `button2` is a in `LinearLayout`:

```
val params = button2?.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
button2?.layoutParams = params
```

or shortly:

```
button2.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
```